# I want to draw a grid on the Windows Phone 7 using XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to draw a grid on the screen of a Windows Phone; it will help me better position my sprites on the screen rather than guessing locations on the screen.

I have found several examples of a grid (2d or 3d) using XNA 3.0, but unfortunately the architectures are different and so the code doesnt work in XNA 4.0

Does anyone have something that could work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a grid that is static on the screen while you move around your camera or is it getting applied to your objects/quads etc? Are you working in 3d or 2d? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Loyoric.  I am working in 2d.  I am trying to use Primitives to show lines (or dots).  Once I learn to do that, I want to display some x,y text coordinates on the screen.  I have some sample code, its a for-loop thats supposed to draw all the lines, but although I have over 80 vertices, only 1 line is displaying.  Something is wrong with this line, but cant figure it out.  getScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineList, vertices3, 0, 40); .   I READ THAT XNA does not have support for basic Lines/Circles, so primitives are harder to do.

Comment: ok, adding more.. I am sort of working in 2d (which is 3d with a z plane set to 0).

Comment: You will be working in 3D then, this can be a bit trickier if you need the grid to be applied to objects relative to the camera. Let me know if the static screen grid is what you were after or if you were looking for something to be applied to object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a `PrimitiveBatch` class here http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/primitives and use the code below to generate an appropriate grid as a texture.

```cs
PrimitiveBatch primitiveBatch;
private Texture2D GenerateGrid(Rectangle destRect, int cols, int rows, Color gridColor, int cellSize)
{
    int w = (int)(cols * gridCellSize);
    int h = (int)(rows * gridCellSize);

    float uselessWidth = destRect.Width - w;
    float uselessHeigth = destRect.Height - h;

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle((int)(uselessWidth / 2) + destRect.X, (int)(uselessHeigth / 2) + destRect.Y, w, h);

    RenderTarget2D grid = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(grid);
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

    primitiveBatch.Begin(PrimitiveType.LineList);

    float x = bounds.X;
    float y = bounds.Y;

    for (int col = 0; col < cols + 1; col++)
    {
        primitiveBatch.AddVertex(new Vector2(x + (col * gridCellSize), bounds.Top), gridColor);
        primitiveBatch.AddVertex(new Vector2(x + (col * gridCellSize), bounds.Bottom), gridColor);
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < rows + 1; row++)
    {
        primitiveBatch.AddVertex(new Vector2(bounds.Left, y + (row * gridCellSize)), gridColor);
        primitiveBatch.AddVertex(new Vector2(bounds.Right, y + (row * gridCellSize)), gridColor);
    }
    primitiveBatch.End();

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty way you can do it (as it is for debugging the quicker the better) is to simply create a texture of a grid that is of the same resolution you are running your XNA game at (if you are running it at the same resolution as the phone, this will be 480x800). Most of the texture will simply be an alpha map and with grid lines of one pixel, you could create multiple resolutions or you can repeat a small texture of a single pixel cross dividing a section of the screen that is divisible by the resolution you are running at.

The draw method will be something as below and be called everyframe.

This code can declared inside your game class

```
Texture2D gridTexture;
Rectangle gridRectangle;
```

This code should be in your LoadContent method

```
//Best to use something like a png file
gridTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>("pathto/mygridtexture");
gridRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,resolutionX,resolutionY);
```

This method should be called from your Draw method last to ensure it is on top assuming you are just using the standard `spriteBatch.Begin()` to render sprites (first if you are doing FrontToBack rendering).

```
public void DrawGrid()
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(gridTexture, gridRectangle, Color.White);
}
```

This grid will remain stationary throughout the running of your application and should be useful when trying to line up your UI or objects that have relative positions in your game.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [XPF project by RedBadger](http://red-badger.com/Blog/post/Introducing-XPF-e28093-A-Layout-Framework-for-XNA.aspx). It enables you to use XAML style layout in an XNA project.